# ios6 vibrate stopped working

Tags: xcode, ios6

I upgraded my iPhone4S to iOS6 today. The vibrate function in my application stopped working. I also upgraded to Xcode4.5 and rebuilt to test. It was still broken. Has anyone else noticed that `kSystemSoundID_Vibrate` has stopped working after upgrading to iOS 6.0?

Comment: I discovered the problem only exists when you set the audio session category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord. If I change it to AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute the vibration starts working.